# Share database connection with packages

Tags: mysql, go

I'm new with golang. I'm trying to share mysql database connection in my package, latter maybe in several packages. To skip defining database connection in every package I've created Database package and now I'm trying to get that package, connect to db and use that object in whole package.

I'm using this mysql plugin: github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

here is my code:

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "./packages/db" // this is my custom database package
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var dbType Database.DatabaseType
var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    log.Printf("-- entering main...")
    dbType := Database.New()
    db = dbType.GetDb()

    dbType.DbConnect()

    delete_test_data()

    dbType.DbClose()
}

func delete_test_data(){
    log.Printf("-- entering delete_test_data...")

    //db.Exec("DELETE FROM test;")
}
```

packages/db/db.go

```
package Database

import (
    "log"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type DatabaseType struct {
   DatabaseObject *sql.DB
}

func New()(d *DatabaseType) {
    d = new(DatabaseType)
    //db.DatabaseObject = db.DbConnect()
    return d
}


func (d *DatabaseType) DbConnect() *DatabaseType{
    log.Printf("-- entering DbConnect...")
    var err error

    if d.DatabaseObject == nil {
        log.Printf("--------- > Database IS NIL...")
        d.DatabaseObject, err = sql.Open("mysql", "...")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        err = d.DatabaseObject.Ping()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
    }

    return d
}

func (d *DatabaseType) DbClose(){
    log.Printf("-- entering DbClose...")
    defer d.DatabaseObject.Close()
}

func (d *DatabaseType) GetDb() *sql.DB{
   return d.DatabaseObject
}
```

Everything is ok and without error until I uncomment this line:

```
db.Exec("DELETE FROM test;")
```

Can someone tell me what is correct way to share db connection?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Further: your `dbType.DbConnect()` method returns a `DatabaseType` with an initialized connection, but you're ignoring the return value entirely.

Comment: @elithrar - you are correct. Typical start mistake

Comment: PS: Have a read of http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access#using-an-interface and https://robots.thoughtbot.com/interface-with-your-database-in-go - it may help simplify the code you have. Could be simpler!

Comment: @elithrar - can you point me what certain of code can I simplify?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: it would be great that who gave mi "vote down" gives an explanation for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dbType.DbConnect()` method returns a `DatabaseType` with an initialized connection, but you're ignoring the return value entirely.

Further - to simplify your code - look at having `New(host string) *DB` instead of *three* different functions (New/DbConnect/GetDb) that do the same thing.

e.g.

```
package datastore

type DB struct {
    // Directly embed this
    *sql.DB
}

func NewDB(host string) (*DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open(...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &DB{db}, nil
}
```

---

```
package main

var db *datastore.DB

func main() {
    var err error
    db, err = datastore.NewDB(host)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err := someFunc()
}

func someFunc() error {
    rows, err := db.Exec("DELETE FROM ...")
    // Handle the error, parse the result, etc.
}
```

This reduces the juggling you have to do, and you can still call close on your DB type because it embeds `*sql.DB` - there's no need to implement your own `Close()` method.